# Trying to get property of non-object on codeigniter in ajax error access

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have a code to cek if the user is exist. I return some data to display to user. This is my code 
**Model**

```
public function cek_exist_master($no_eir){
    $this->db->select('REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID, EIR_REF');
    $this->db->where('EIR_REF', $no_eir);
    $query = $this->db->get('tb_master_repair_estimate');
    return $query;
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$cek_master =$this->m_surveyor->cek_exist_master($this->input->post('EIR_REF'));
echo $cek_master->row()->REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID;
```

And this is the database looked like :

```
mysql> desc tb_master_repair_estimate;
+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type                  | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID | int(11)               | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| EIR_REF            | varchar(30)           | YES  | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| NO_TANK            | int(11)               | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| COSTUMER_ID        | int(11)               | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| TANK_ID            | int(11)               | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

24 rows in set (0.01 sec)

CI gives me an error like this,

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: surveyor/c_surveyor.php
```

Any help it so appreciate

**Update**,

Sorry, have bad copy paste on stackoverflow. I still get those error untill Now

Comment: can you check what is coming in variable `$cek_master`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the **$** sign in your controller. It should be:

```
$cek_master = $this->m_surveyor->cek_exist_master($this->input->post('EIR_REF'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a typo?

```
$cek_master = this->m_surveyor->...
```

Should be

```
$cek_master = $this->m_surveyor->...
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that you load your model "m_surveyor" into controller.

Answer (score 0):

CONTROLLER.. Change in controller code

```
$cek_master =this->m_surveyor->cek_exist_master($this->input->post('EIR_REF'));

echo is_object($cek_master->row()) ? $cek_master->row()->REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID : '';
```